# How to parse ISO-8859-1 encoded Form Data in Parameters in Jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using Jmeter for recording my Application. I used Recording Controller template in Jmeter. When I tried to execute my script, I am getting an error message as Response code:400 & Response message:Bad Request. Could someone please help me how to read 'Form Data' in Request body?

I have tried

1. 'Content-Type: as application/x-www-form-urlencoded' but did not work.

Below are screenshots of my application

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images quality is too bad therefore we cannot comment on "how to read" the data. If you want us to analyze your request payload you should [add it as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) in addition to the image.

Your `Content-Type` header will be ignored as you have `Use multipart/form-data for HTTP POST` so you're sending `multipart/form-data` Content-Type

If you recorded your request and it fails on replay most probably it happens due to one of the following reasons:

1. The request operation cannot be repeated due to test data has been used already, i.e. if the request creates a folder with name "test" first execution will succeed and second and subsequent will fail because the folder already exists. In this case you might want to parameterize your request and use random/unique data
2. Missing or improperly working [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter), the most obvious option to proceed is:

   - Use a 3rd-party sniffer tool to capture the request from JMeter and from the real browser
   - Compare the requests - they must be absolutely the same (apart from dynamic values which need to be correlated)
   - Once JMeter will send the same request as

   if the request body is encoded and cannot be read most probably the encoding is done using client-side [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/), you need to locate this function, determine what it does and come up with the decryption code somewhere in JSR223 Test Elements [enter link description here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri. My Request was failing because 1) the operation cannot be repeated due to test data. 2) Encoding was done on Client side Javascript and we asked developers to remove encoding and they did it.